# Google Chrome Inspect Element Bypassing a Restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a social network called miiverse, once you post, you have to wait 3 minutes to post again. I am trying to get around this.

The buttons elements say

input type="submit" class="black-button post-button" value="Send" data-sitecatalyst-action="postSubmit" data-sitecatalyst-event="event22" data-sitecatalyst-var-names="eVar21 eVar25 eVar26" data-sitecatalyst-var-evar21="text" data-sitecatalyst-var-evar25="14866558073037299863" data-sitecatalyst-var-evar26="14866558073037299866">

When you click the button, at the beginning, class="black-button post-button" becomes class="black-button post-button loading disabled", but only for a second. After that, a window pops up saying "Please wait 3 minutes before posting" Is there anyway to stop the loading, or the window?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hacking a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is against this site's terms of use (and I'd personally not like to help you break them). If they built in a restriction in posting, then you shouldn't evade that by using some tricks. Besides, if they're not complete idiots, they've also built in server-side verification. And going by the way their popup works, I'd say they're not complete idiots.

Answer (score 0):

The validation 99,99% is on the server side, so you have no change to pass by the pop up.